# Difference between file created in github and one pushed to github?

Tags: git, github, diff

I created a file in repo X using the github GUI (i.e. the little plus sign next to the repo's name), resulting in a commit line in the history for `X/filename` that says "Create filename". Then I deleted the file and wrote a new one from gitbash (in Windows) using `echo "file contents" > filename`, which I added, committed, and pushed. There is now another line in history that looks identical to the original "Create filename" line.

Is there a difference between the underlying functionality of these two commit methods and if so, is there any way to detect that by reading the history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Not really

You can look at the raw commit on github by appending `.patch` to a commit url; doing so you'll likely draw the conclusion "no" it's not possible to identify commits done via github's web-editor.

### But it's possible in specific circumstances

By inspection you may find that there are some indicators that permit identifying the source.

For example, compare [this commit](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/app-template/commit/6b766cd443de8d0694438cab9455517f851d817a.patch):

```
From 6b766cd443de8d0694438cab9455517f851d817a Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: AD7six <andydawson76@gmail.com>
Date: Wed, 26 Mar 2014 16:57:58 +0000
Subject: [PATCH] Make the pages controller throw 404s
```

with [this commit](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/app-template/commit/234407bbaa41333f077243bef32c2317692f440d.patch):

```
From 234407bbaa41333f077243bef32c2317692f440d Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Andy Dawson <andydawson76@gmail.com>
Date: Sat, 31 May 2014 18:42:22 +0200
Subject: [PATCH] add more descriptive env/dsn docs
```

There is a subtle but clear indicator (to me) which commits were made via github's web interface:

```
From: AD7six <andydawson76@gmail.com>
      ^ normal commit
From: Andy Dawson <andydawson76@gmail.com>
      ^ Github UI
```

The first comes from my own `git config user.name` setting, wheras the second is my name as shown on [github](https://github.com/AD7six#Class::method).

This is one example scenario whereby it becomes possible to identify a commit made via Github's UI rather than as a normal git commit.

Answer (score 2):

The github UI and command line manipulate the git repository in the same way. There is no such concept as "came from remote" vs "local", as the entire history of a branch is synced/merged on a push. The only way to track differences is by appropriate commit comments.

github could use git notes or templating on commit messages to differentiate the UI commits, but as far as i know there is no such option at this time.